# After rooting my Samsung Galaxy S7 with Odin Windows Tool, I am locked out of my phone

Tags: rooting, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have followed the instructions [here](http://mobilesiri.com/galaxy-s7-edge-exynos-root/) and used Odin to root my Galaxy S7 edge. During the process the phone has rebooted and is now asking for my draw pattern. However, it won't accept my pattern. Any suggestions...?

Comment: Tried to enter recovery?

Comment: I had to do a factory reset. Luckily it didn't matter since this was a new phone with nothing of importance on it, otherwise I would have been screwed. I strongly advise anyone attempting this to firstly remove all security locks from your phone.